# After sending to app store, can't run the original xcode project on my iPad

Tags: xcode, code-signing, app-store

It took me a while, and some help from Apple (one instruction I missed), but I finally was able to submit an app to the app store (still waiting for acceptance/rejection.)

But I went into xcode and started up the app again, and now I can't run it on my iPad. I get a code signing error. It does run on the simulator.

I know it's something simple...what am I missing?

-Rob

Comment: Are you still building with a scheme that uses the Distribution profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're still using the distribution code signing identity.

Assuming you're using Xcode 4.2, you can refer to the bellow image for how to change this:

[edit: better image]
[image]

You also need to change your application identifier to match your code signing identity:

[image]

So, look at the string next to the selection you choose in the step 4 of the first screenshot (probably something in the format of com.yourcompany.appname) and make sure to use that same identifier in step 4 of the second screenshot.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I tried every choice I had in Step 4 and I am still getting the Failed error when I'm trying to go to my iPad. And I was so happy that I made it all the way through to app submission after selecting the correct distribution line.

Comment: @RobSmythe - Sounds like you also need to change the Identifier in the summary section; see my updated answer.  If that doesn't work, try giving more details. Like, what is the exact error you're receiving?

Comment: I'm amazed. Something I did worked (before performing your second suggestion). I tried to run every time I made a change, so I could see what made the difference. But I might have made a couple of changes the last time. Unlike your screen dump above, I have a drop down triangle at "Code Signing Entitlements" above "Code Signing Identity". I clicked on Debug - Any SDK (not shown above) and the run succeeded. Strange. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You might have missed something really simple. Check the certificate installed in your Mac keychain as well as on the iPad. There appears to be nothing wrong with your app since it's running fine in the simulator.